# Fitting portrait png/jpg in viewport

Tags: android, html, webview, orientation, viewport

Background:

- I am using the WebView from Android's SDK to display images from the web.
- The WebView is in landscape setting (width longer than the height)
- I managed to wrap the image reference with some light HTML(5) code w/ Viewport as the META

Problem:

- The portrait images are being displayed in landscape...very weird

What I already tried:
* I tried the "image-orientation" attribute in the css for the IMG tag...doesn't work

Sample HTML:

`<html>
<head>
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=1520, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0\">
</head>
<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center><img src = "http://storage.googleapis.com/myfolder/mypic.jpg" style="width: auto; height: auto; max-height: 100%;" />
</body>
</html>`

Can anyone offer any advice on how resolve any of the above cases?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the jpg doesn't rotate correctly.  I found the information to

1. obtain the exif information stored in the jpg
     ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(localFilePath);

   ```
   int currentOrientation = Integer.valueOf(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
   ```
2. create a new copy in the temporary storage
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFilePath);

   ```
   bitmap = BitmapUtil.rotate(currentOrientation, bitmap);
   ```
3. rotate it 
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

   ```
   matrix.postRotate(getRotationAngle(currentOrientation));

   return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
   ```